# read file from external storage

Tags: android, storage, external, readfile

I simply cannot find how to get one specified file from the external storage. 
I know that with getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(), you get the external storage directory but I can't get further. I need some kind of method where you have to give the name of the file and it returns the file.
Thanx

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Better than using `File.separator` is this, which is standard Java:

```
final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                          .getAbsolutePath(), filename);
```

Comment: if you get file path at specific name then what happen with file

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 6):

You can just do this:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            .getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + fileName);
```

Answer (score 3):

Better still:

```
final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also use getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() and everything goes well. My filename is "DE Disimpan"

```
File file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
File filepath = new File(file,"DE Disimpan");
```